# Edit Gridview columns to MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

When I try my code to update the `GridViewBox` to update to my database I get the following error message

> Object Reference not set to an instance of an Object

But I cannot quite figure it out. Would appreciate any Help I can get.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1

    //GLOBAL DELARATION
    Dim conString As String = "Server=xxx;" & "Database=xxx;" & "Uid=xxx;" & "xxx;"
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(conString)
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim adapter As MySqlDataAdapter

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        //TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'OlejnaDataSet.people' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.PeopleTableAdapter.Fill(Me.OlejnaDataSet.people)
        DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

    End Sub

    Private Sub hent()
        Me.PeopleTableAdapter.Fill(Me.OlejnaDataSet.people)
    End Sub

    Private Sub cleartxt()
        TextBox_name.Text = ""
        TextBox_position.Text = ""
        TextBox_team.Text = ""

    End Sub

    Private Sub Add()
        Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO people(Name,Position,Team) VALUES(@NAME,@POSITION,@TEAM)"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)

        //PARAMETERS
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", TextBox_name.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POSITION", TextBox_position.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEAM", TextBox_team.Text)

        //Open Connection and INSERT
        Try
            con.Open()
            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Added")
                cleartxt()
            End If
            con.Close()
            hent()
        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    //UPDATE DATABASE
    Private Sub UpdateDG(id As String)
        Dim sql As String = "UPDATE people SET name='" + TextBox_name.Text + "', position='" + TextBox_position.Text + "', team='" + TextBox_team.Text + "' WHERE ID='" + id + "'"

        //Open CON, EXECUTE UPDATE, CLOSE

        Try
            con.Open()
            adapter.UpdateCommand = con.CreateCommand()
            adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = sql

            If adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
                MsgBox("You have now updated")
                cleartxt()
            End If
            con.Close()
            //REFRESH
            hent()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            con.Close()

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonAdd.Click
        Add()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonDelete.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonUpdate.Click
        Dim id As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
        UpdateDG(id)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseClick
        Dim name As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value
        Dim position As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value
        Dim team As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value

        TextBox_name.Text = name
        TextBox_position.Text = position
        TextBox_team.Text = team
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: In which line, did you get the error?

Comment: I get the error directly from the GridView - the form still running: http://postimg.org/image/4a2dzp8vn/

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have clicked `Update` `button` without select any rows in your `DataGrid`

Change your `Update` Button `Click` Event as follows:

```
 Private Sub ButtonUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonUpdate.Click
     If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim id As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
        UpdateDG(id)
     End If
 End Sub
```

**Update**

Please Declare and Intialize your `Sql Adapter`

Use as below:

`SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();`

```
    //UPDATE DATABASE
    Private Sub UpdateDG(id As String)
        Dim sql As String = "UPDATE people SET name='" + TextBox_name.Text + "', position='" + TextBox_position.Text + "', team='" + TextBox_team.Text + "' WHERE ID='" + id + "'"

        //Open CON, EXECUTE UPDATE, CLOSE

        Try
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            con.Open()
            adapter.UpdateCommand = con.CreateCommand()
            adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = sql
            If adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
                MsgBox("You have now updated")
                cleartxt()
            End If
            con.Close()
            //REFRESH
            hent()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank for your input, but I'm still having the same problem: http://postimg.org/image/4a2dzp8vn/

Comment: Debug your code and find in which line cause the error

Comment: I get the error on line 60: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DataGridView.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


http://postimg.org/image/vdvmguihx/